# I thought my pc had bluetooth. I bought a bluetooth mouse, now what?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I bought a Microsoft Bluetooth mouse. My Vista laptop does not have built-in bluetooth. Can anyone recommend a good bluetooth USB adaptor to make this thing work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for a laptop I'd be tempted to try something like [this](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=usb+bluetooth+adapter&cid=8715917796457838574&ei=sMvtS5zZHoGz-Ab_xMXcDQ&sa=title&ved=0CA0Q8wIwATgA#p), [this](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=usb+bluetooth+adapter&cid=8752442867801057290&ei=sMvtS5zZHoGz-Ab_xMXcDQ&sa=title&ved=0CB0Q8wIwBDgA#p) or [this](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=usb+bluetooth+adapter&cid=2711281918345890955&ei=sMvtS5zZHoGz-Ab_xMXcDQ&sa=title&ved=0CDMQ8wIwCDgA#p).

[image]

They're all mini adapters that you should be able to leave plugged in without fear of it being knocked out or damaged.

Comment: You might not even have to pay that much. I picked up a mini-USB bluetooth adaptor like that from the local pound shop. Time will tell on quality/longevity, but it seems to work perfectly well. If they can be had from there for 1ukp I'm sure you'll find them cheap elsewhere too.

Comment: @David - I just linked to the shopping results pages because they were the first (and easiest) to find. I was highlighting that you can get mini adapters which seem ideal for laptops.

Comment: I wasn't criticising your answer, just pointing out that I'd seen working options in surprisingly cheap places. Mini-usb adaptors are indeed very useful - I have a bluetooth ones and a similarly sized microSD adaptor almost permanently attached to my netbook.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of buying a bluetooth adapter and the new mouse is probably higher than if you simply return the mouse and get a regular wireless mouse (all of which now include usb receivers).  I know it's probably not the answer you are expecting but it's the "easiest" way to get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

I went for [this one](http://us.kensington.com/html/14409.html). It blinks (blue) when active and blinks quickly when in use, but it's on the back of my laptop so what do I care.